# Remove a record from a Grid Locally

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a `Grid` in a `Window`. When i click on a row of that window and click on the remove button, that row should get removed from the window. (I think i will have to `remove it from Store and reload the grid, so the changes will be picked`)

I am unable to get the click event and remove the row from the store. I have added the button for this but not able to get the Grid record and remove it from store and reloading it.

My code is as follows;

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Boy', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.boy',
    height: 800,
    width: 900,
    layout: {
        type: 'absolute'
    },
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'gridpanel',
                    height: 500,
                    width: 800,
                    title: 'My Grid Panel',
                    store: 'School',
                    viewConfig: {
                    },
                    columns: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                            dataIndex: 'Id',
                            text: 'id'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                            dataIndex: 'name',
                            text: 'name'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    height: 40,
                    width: 150,
                    text: 'Remove',
                    listeners: {
                        click: {
                            fn: me.removebuttonclick,
                            scope: me
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    },
    removebuttonclick: function(button, e, options) {
        console.log('removebuttonclick');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Boy', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.boy',
    height: 800,
    width: 900,
    layout: {
        type: 'absolute'
    },
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        var this.grid = Ext.widget({
                    xtype: 'gridpanel',
                    height: 500,
                    width: 800,
                    title: 'My Grid Panel',
                    store: 'School',
                    viewConfig: {
                    },
                    columns: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                            dataIndex: 'Id',
                            text: 'id'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                            dataIndex: 'name',
                            text: 'name'
                        }
                    ]
                });
        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [
                this.grid, //oopsie
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    height: 40,
                    width: 150,
                    text: 'Remove',
                    listeners: {
                        click: {
                            fn: me.removebuttonclick,
                            scope: me
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    },
    removebuttonclick: function(button, e, options) {
    var me = this;
    Ext.Array.each(this.grid.getSelectionModel().selected,function(record, index,selectedRows){
            me.grid.getStore().remove(record);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I get `TypeError: this.grid is undefined` how do i solve this ?

Comment: Instead of using grid like the way you specified, is there a way to get the `grid` using the parameter `button` ?

Comment: Sorry, fixed the type error in the example. Uhm, to do it without this.grid is possible, but you'll end up doing various different hacks ( eg pass the scope of the click as the grid, and then just do this.getSm() etc, or declaring the remove function directly in the config, or using absolute Id's, or walk up the dom and then back down again ( more complex than it sounds ) )